# Create an alias - in Bash?

Tags: bash, alias, bash-alias

How can I create an alias named `-` in Bash? None of the following works:

```
alias -='cd -'
alias \-='cd -'
alias '-'='cd -'
```

with error:

```
bash: alias: -=: invalid option
alias: usage: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

```
alias -- -='cd -'
```

`--` is often used (especially with Gnu programs) to stop parsing the following arguments as options. That's also how you can e.g. `rm` files whose names start with `-`.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks a bunch. Seems to work like a charm.